# What mod added this little yellow icon to Skyrim's HUD?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I have a lot of mods installed. One of them added a small yellow icon to the lower left hand side of my screen:

[image: Screenshot of above-described icon]

[image: Zoomed-in screenshot]

It goes away while I am in menus but otherwise it is always there. I would love to know if anyone has any idea which mod is causing it.

I am running 167 active mods. So unless there is some way to export a list from Nexus Mod Manager it will be very time consuming to provide a mod list. Thanks in advance for the help.

If you are going to vote this question down please consider telling me how to improve it. Thanks.

Comment: Is one of those 167 mods the "add little yellow icons" mod?

Comment: any idea for a better way to word the question? lol

Comment: I suggest using a binary search method to narrow down which mod it is. With 167 possibilities it shouldn't take too many iterations to work it out. Expecting someone to know exactly what mod makes that icon is being remarkably optimistic.

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: Disable half of the mods, see if problem persists. If yes, you know it's not in those you disabled. If no, then you know it is. Repeat the process seven or eight times and you'll have your answer.

Comment: @ChrisBolton Essentially, disable half your mods. If the problem is still there, you'll know it's only in the 83 mods remaining. Keep doing so until you've found it. You should only have to repeat the process 7 times maximum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is from the mod [Clean up your Corpses](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/59340/?), you can disable or move it via the mod configuration menu, "CUYC" and the widget tab there.

Comment: I was like "Hey! I recognize that little yellow icon"

Comment: I was hoping something like that would happen. :)